# What does '&' mean in C++?

Tags: c++, c

What does '&' mean in C++?

As within the function

```
void Read_wav::read_wav(const string &filename)
{

}
```

And what is its equivalent in C?

If I want to transform the above C++ function into a C function, how would I do it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: as @Tim Medora said http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29 (but I 've corrected the link ;))

Comment: @Hernán Eche - Paste fail on my part...Thanks!

Comment: "If I want to transform the above C++ function into a C function, how would I do it?" 1. Stop using classes. 2. Stop using strings. 3. Stop using pass by reference.

Comment: While the answers apply _to this situation_, keep in mind that the [ampersand (&) can mean other things](https://dev.to/sandordargo/how-to-use-ampersands-in-c-3kga) in C++ as well.

Comment: To complete David Heffernan's comment above: 4.Learn to do memory management.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In that context, the & makes the variable a reference.

Usually, when you pass an variable to a function, the variable is copied and the function works on the copy. When the function returns, your original variable is unchanged. When you pass a reference, no copy is made and changes made by the function show up even after the function returns.

C doesn't have references, but a C++ reference is functionally the same as a pointer in C. Really the only difference is that pointers have to be dereferenced when you use them:

```
    *filename = "file.wav";
```

But references can be used as though they were the original variable:

```
    filename = "file.wav";
```

Ostensibly, references are supposed to never be null, although it's not impossible for that to happen.

The equivalent C function would be:

```
     void read_wav(const char* filename)
     {

     }
```

This is because C doesn't have `string`. Usual practice in C is to send a pointer to an array of characters when you need a string. As in C++, if you type a string constant

```
    read_wav("file.wav");
```

The type is `const char*`.

Comment: "*Ostensibly, references are supposed to never be null, although it's not impossible for that to happen.*" That is UB. If you spot a null reference while debugging, the program is likely broken with memory corruption happening.

Answer (score 12):

It means that the variable is a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29). There is no direct equivalent in C. You can think of it as a pointer that is automatically dereferenced when used, and can never be NULL, maybe.

The typical way to represent a string in C is by a `char` pointer, so the function would likely look like this:

```
void read_wav(struct Read_wav* instance, const char *filename)
{
}
```

Note: the first argument here simulates the implicit `this` object reference you would have in C++, since this looks like a member method.

Comment: you need a reference to the original struct as well -- based on the usage, internals from the Read_wav class are being used

Comment: although unlikely, `std::string const& filename` might contain embedded null characters, to perfectly emulate `std::string` you'll need to supply an explicit `length` parameter. Or, like I did, go for the `bstring` library.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you would write it this way:

```
void read_wav(struct Read_wav* , const char * pSzFileName)
{

}
```

std::string is the C++ way of dealing with array of const char.

& is a C++ reference. It behaves just as if you were handling the pointer behind ( its is mainly a syntactic sugar, thought it prompts the contract that the pointer behind should not be null).

Comment: You'd only write it that way if it was `static`.  A non-static member function would require an explicit `Read_wav*` argument to replace the implicit `this` from C++.

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand is used in two different meanings in C++: obtaining an address of something (e.g. of a variable or a function) and specifying a variable or function parameter to be a reference to an entity defined somewhere else. In your example, the latter meaning is in use.

C does not have strictly speaking anything like the reference but pointers (or pointers to pointers) have been user for ages for similar things.

See e.g. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html, [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/difference-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c) or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29 for more information about references in C++.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, std::string has a c_str method which returns a const char *.  You can make a parallel C version and then have your C++ do something like:

```
void Read_wav::read_wav(const string &filename)
{
    do_read_wav(internal_read_wav, filename.c_str());
}
```

where do_read_wav is your C routine and internal_read_wav is a pointer to a C-style struct.

```
void do_read_wav(struct Read_wav rw, const char * filename)
```

Now, if you are storing information in the class, you need to make a C struct [all of the fields must be POD, etc]

Answer (score 1):

References are aliases, they are very similar to pointers.

`std::string` is an array of `char` with an explicit `length` (that is, there can be null characters embedded within).

There is a C-library to emulate `std::string` (that is, provide an encapsulated interface) called `bstring` for [Better String Library](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/). It relieves you from the tedium of having to deal with two distinct variables (array and length).

You cannot use classes in `C`, but you can emulate them with forwarded struct (to impose encapsulation) and class methods simply become regular functions with an explicit parameter.

Altogether, this leads to the following transformation:

```
void Read_wav::read_wav(const string &filename);

void read_wav(struct Read_wav* this, struct bstring const* filename);
```

Which (apart from the `struct` noise) is very similar to what you had before :)

Answer (score 0):

& means that variable is passed via reference. So, inside your function you will have not a local copy of variable, but the original variable itself. All the changes to the variable inside the function will influence the original passed variable.

Comment: well it's true but in his case as there is a const-qualifier, the variable will not be changed

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Binky Pointer fun](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/), it's a video that illustrates what Pointers and References are.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `string &filename` means the function will receive a reference (a memory address) as a parameter, instead of receiving it as a copy.

The advantage of this method is that your function will not allocate more space on the stack to save the data contained in *filename*.

Answer (score 0):

It's a reference, as others have said.
In C, you'd probably write the function as something like

```
void read_wav(struct Read_wav* rw, const char* filename)
{

}
```

Comment: @Foo Bah: Or even `const char * const filename` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int num = 7;

    int& a = num; // reference to the num variable
    int* b = &num; // a variable that stores the address of the num 
    variable
    int c = *b; // the * operator retrieves the value from the variable b, 
    which stores the address of the variable num

    num += 1;

    cout << a << endl; //since a is a reference to the variable num, by 
    changing num we change the value of the variable a
    cout << *b;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

&filename means this is a reference to filename.

Comment: There is no such thing as pass by reference in C. This code does not compile in C.